# What sql statement can I write to get all the linking tracks to an album

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to think of an SQL statement I can write up in MySQL in which I can get all the tracks included inside an album. The way I have it set up is Album_id which is the primary key to my album table is linked inside the tracks table in the form of a foreign key. That way each track row is linked to an album in the album table.

I'll further detail below the layout of my tables:

**tbl_Albums**

As you can see I have the Album_id as the primary key and it's auto_incremented so the id will automatically update when a new row is entered.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Albums` (
`Album_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`Album_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`Number_Of_Tracks` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Genre` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`Artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Album_id`),
 KEY `Artist_id` (`Artist_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Albums_ibfk_2` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Artist_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Artist` (`Artist_id`))
```

**tbl_Tracks**

Inside the tracks table I set a foreign key with album_id, so I link the tracks to a specific album.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Tracks` (
`Track_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`Track_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`Length` time NOT NULL,
`Artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Track_id`),
 KEY `Artist_id` (`Artist_id`),
 KEY `Album_id` (`Album_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Tracks_ibfk_1` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Artist_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Artist` (`Artist_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Tracks_ibfk_2` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Album_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Albums` (`Album_id`))
```

I have the tables linked properly, but I'm trying to think of an MySQL statement that can allow me to show all the tracks linked to a specific album and have come up empty so far. I'm then trying to implement the code into a php form for a user to use to list out the tracks

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT
      `t2`.*
    FROM
      `tbl_Albums` `t1`
    INNER JOIN
      `tbl_Tracks` `t2`
    ON
      `t2`.`Album_id`=`t1`.`Album_id`
    WHERE
      `t1`.`Album_Name`='Name of Your album'
    ORDER BY
       `t2`.`Track_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tbl_Albums.Album_id, tbl_Albums.Album_Name, tbl_Tracks.Track_id, tbl_Tracks.Track_Name, tbl_Tracks.Album_id
FROM tbl_Albums

INNER JOIN tbl_Tracks ON tbl_Albums.Album_id = tbl_Tracks.Album_id WHERE
  `tbl_Albums`.`Album_Name`='Your album name'
ORDER BY
   `tbl_Tracks`.`Track_id`;
```

Comment: This code is what i'm looking for, but what it's doing is display all the tracks and all their linking albums. I'm wanting to insert it into a php form in which a user would specify an album, and then it's linking tracks would show. Is there any way to alter the code you've shown to display something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correct, but a simple select should do the trick?

If you know the album id, for instance 5:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_Tracks` WHERE `Album_id` = 5;
```

If you know the album name:

```
SELECT `t`.* FROM `tbl_Tracks` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_Albums` AS `a` ON `a`.`Album_id` = `t`.`Album_id`
WHERE `a`.`Album_Name` = 'Thriller';
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned that the main reason I'm using this code is for a query in a php form

Comment: I was trying to do it in steps, if I had the statement, i could then implement it into a query. Would I simply do `$result=SELECT `t`.* FROM `tbl_Tracks` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_Albums` AS `a` ON `a`.`Album_id` = `t`.`Album_id`
WHERE `a`.`Album_Name` = ''";`